# How to show in finder from Spotlight?

Tags: mac, spotlight

Often I use Spotlight to find some file, but then I'd like to see where that file is. My natural reaction is to right-click and select "show in Finder", but alas no such thing seems to be possible. Is there some trick I'm missing?

I'm aware there is also a search in Finder itself, but it isn't quite as convenient as cmd-space.

[image]

For example how to see where footer.inc is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [here](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/):

> Reveal the selected item in the Finder
>   In Spotlight Menu: Cmd-click item or press Cmd-Return
>   In Spotlight Window: Press Cmd-R